# file upload in react + typescript without using JQuery?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, file-upload, react-redux

I want to upload a file from a client to the server using only react (with typescript) without JQuery.  I'm not able to find any solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this:

In your `render()`:

```
<input type="file" onChange={(e) => this.handleFileUpload(e)} />
```

And your `onChange` handler:

```
private handleFileUpload({ files })
{
  const file = files[0];

  // send file to server here the way you need
}
```

Answer (score 0):

https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-firebase-file-uploader 
This will work for you for sure, as i also used this